How to handle a boss who likes wasting your time?
I work for a contractual research organization, and my lab specifically deals with trace metals analyses using ICP-MS, ICP-OES and AAS instruments, and I'm a fresher.
Even though I unquestionably understand and know things (this has been told to me not just by the seniors from my own department, but even managers from other departments feel this way and have told my fellow colleagues so), only my manager doesn't want me to be working on the machines even after having being in the laboratory for over three months now.. The "analyst qualification" (only after which can I be using the instruments and doing analyses) seems to be getting delayed even though he'd promised me to be ensuring it be done right after 45 days (company policy for minimum time to be taken for the same). I have asked him if I lack knowledge in any sense of the word, to please let me know so that I can learn and then go for the analyst qualification, but he has been unable to stop me on that front. He keeps saying things like "wait, it will happen" or "some things are not under our control" or "there are no samples". The last one especially irks me because I witness analyses happening every day.
Thereafter, he's told me that my "primary work" is to simply scan data documents that analysts are generating. More often than not, he asks me to stay after office hours saying that a senior is now preparing the documents (it's all handwritten, apart from primary machine generated data) and that I need to scan the documents and then leave. This takes a couple of hours, so I'm having to just literally loiter around in the laboratory while some senior is preparing the document, till they're done, then scan the papers and then leave. The women, however, are only given tasks that let them stay till the clock runs.
We have no overtime pay. This is a major reason why I don't like staying after-hours. Coupled with that, my current salary is just enough for basic survival, i.e. Being able to share a room with 3 others. Not an apartment, a room.
I have tried utilizing this time by asking my manager to teach me something but he just never does it. He'd pretend to be busy reading documents that are of no immediate use while I ask, and shortly after, get up and chat with other colleagues.
How do I handle this situation?
I'm considering going to my senior manager and seeking his advice on what I should do in such situations but I'm afraid it might backfire.
Oh, I'm also on probation and it'd last for six months. The company has never fired an employee, even when they're committing mistakes that render instruments useless for over a week.
Sending emails is not an option for me either.. The company doesn't issue emails to employees lower than managerial level.

After seeing your name - have you tried a Pan Galactic Gargleblaster?

@TheDemonLord I do try to beer my pain from time to time, but often end up whiskying it.

"The women, however, are only given tasks that let them stay till the clock runs." Unless there is an allegation of sexism here, I strongly suggest you rephrase this. This question is already flirting with many topics all at once, and implied sexism in the workplace would definitely constitute a question in and of itself.

Where is this? Could you get your hours changed from 11 AM to 8 PM?

"my manager doesn't want me to be working on the machines" Are these machines somehow safety-related? Because no sensible boss in the world is letting you work on dangerous machines with no training. Plus they absolutely need the paperwork involved to go through, as proof that they have given you the training too.

@StephanBranczyk, it's India. I can't.

@Flater I know full well, and yes, I am sure of the sexism in the workplace. The management is open about it. Well... Reverse? Sexism?

Okay so there's a lot to unpack in this question. I'm deconstructing this and addressing specific points, not to suggest that there is a singular "you're wrong" or "you're right" answer to this, but to help you identify the individual issues here that you would be better served addressing separately.

How to handle a boss who likes wasting your time?

While you're on the clock, and they're paying your salary, it's their time, not yours. I mention this because "you're wasting my time" is not a productive argument to add to a workplace dispute with your manager who actually decides your assigned tasks.

We have no overtime pay. This is a major reason why I don't like staying after-hours.

Without a location, it's not possible to judge whether this is a cultural norm or not. Right now I could only provide my personal opinion on unpaid overtime, which is neither here nor there for the purpose of this answer.
Overtime aside, the overall gist of your question isn't so much that your time is being wasted, but that you'd rather be doing other things during your work time. That's a very different discussion to have.

The "analyst qualification" (only after which can I be using the instruments and doing analyses)

We can address the delays you're enduring for this qualification (and I will get to that), but the necessity of having a qualification renders your allegations of "your time being wasted" moot. Right now, you are officially unqualified to operate the machines, your "unquestionable knowledge and understanding" is irrelevant if not backed by the proper certification.

The "analyst qualification" [..] seems to be getting delayed even though he'd promised me to be ensuring it be done right after 45 days. [..] He keeps saying things like "wait, it will happen" or "some things are not under our control" or "there are no samples".

There's no way for anyone here to discern if the feedback you're receiving is genuine or not. We don't know the requirements for the certification, be they budgetary, scheduling, capped based on staff count, requiring specific samples that fit within the certification criteria, ...
On the assumption that it is not genuine, then this simply needs to be tackled as such. Is the manager required to let you take the certification exam? Because if they're not, then what power do you have here? At best, you can then identify that this workplace stagnates your growth and you should decide whether you would rather look for another job.
If they are required to let you take the certification exam, and you have proof of being disingenuously delayed, then that is something you escalate to either HR, your manager's manager, or an external board that is responsible for such things - the correct escalation path depends on context that we don't have.
If you have a case here because they are required to let you certify, you should address this via email. Which brings me to:

Sending emails is not an option for me either.. The company doesn't issue emails to employees lower than managerial level.

Sending an email is always an option, you just would be doing it from a non-work account.

I have asked him if I lack knowledge in any sense of the word


"wait, it will happen" or "some things are not under our control" or "there are no samples"

Your response as to "knowing things" is a non-sequitur. You're being given reasons unrelated to knowledge as to why you haven't been given a chance to take that certification exam.
With all the unknowns here, I'm unwilling to blindly err in your favor here because your argumentation rests solely on two assertions of "knowing things" - which is a cognitive bias that isn't proof in and of itself, and you've quoted your manager referencing other considerations that go into setting up a certification exam. I'm not convinced that the full picture has been painted in this question as it is currently written.

Oh, I'm also on probation and it'd last for six months.

Have you considered that this is maybe why the company is unwilling to invest in your certification at this time?

The company has never fired an employee, even when they're committing mistakes that render instruments useless for over a week.

I don't see what this adds to the question, it's just an off-handed mention that other people have made mistakes on occasion.

The women, however, are only given tasks that let them stay till the clock runs.

Either you're alleging that there is sexism in the workplace, or I strongly suggest you refrain from using gender in your argumentation.

I have tried utilizing this time by asking my manager to teach me something but he just never does it.

Is it their job to do so?

He'd pretend to be busy reading documents

I'd be very careful with judging others' work ethic, definitely that of the person you report to, unless you have irrefutable proof and it is meaningfully relevant to the conversation.

documents  that are of no immediate use

That is not your call to make.

and shortly after, get up and chat with other colleagues.

Management roles often involve discussion with others. Also, again not your call to make whether this is relevant or not.

While I do believe that there is an underlying truth in your frustation, your argumentation raises certain concerns.

You argue that you unquestionably know things, which is an odd thing to assert.
You use that knowledge as the sole justification as to why you should be certified by now and why your time is being wasted on other tasks instead
You argue the irrelevance of your manager's activities, seemingly in a way to argue the importance of the attention they should be giving you instead
You argue the mistakes made by others, seemingly in a way to argue why you being on probation is pointless
You don't actually respond to the specific feedback points you're getting as to why the certification exam is delayed.
There is an odd reference to gendered discrimination, coming seemingly out of nowhere.

I'm not dismissing that your manager might be delaying your certification, but I've got an equally likely suspicion that you're not presenting the big picture in the question you've posted, and your attitude about this situation is not as productive as it could be.
Based on how you're currently arguing your case, I suggest you don't continue on this track. Instead, I suggest you reassess your situation and the argumentation that you're employing to point out any issues that you're dealing with.

1/idk how many. My problem is with what I'm asked to do after-hours, not during. I'm from India, and the industry standard is to be paying overtime, not otherwise. My knowledge of the instrument is because I've worked with a similar one during my Master degree, MALDI-TOF. They both have quite a similar principle of working, ICP-MS. My knowledge stems from there and my manager is well aware of it. The "qualification" is simply a company thing which, no matter how experienced one is, they have to undergo after a minimum of 45 days. (hence the number). They usually go for it after 3 months.

2/idk how many. As for the sexism part, it's out in the open, for all of the company. They're given smaller tasks and are considered as needing to be leaving on time for "safety reasons" while seemingly none exist in a metropolis. The job of my manager is actually to be making sure that analysts are qualified for the job, so yes, it is a part of his job to be teaching me anything that I require to know to be able to use the machine(s). Documents.. They're COAs (multiple instances) which are of yesteryear.. As for his discussions they do not involve work.. That I have witnessed for myself.

As for knowing things unquestionably, I have an Master of Technology degree. Most people around have a Master of Science degree, which is considered equivalent to Bachelor of Technology degree here in India (officially, even by the government). Moreover, I have a whole year of research experience that both Master of Science and Bachelor of Technology degree holders lack, and on top of that, I have an experience with a similar instrument that I am supposed to be working with.

@ZaphodBeeblebrox (1) All of these points still ignore the specific certification required to operate the machine. There are plenty of reasons for that certification to be a requirement, be they safety or not damaging the machine. What your boss knows about your skill level would mean nothing if the insurance is unwilling to pay out any claim if the company let an uncertified individual operate the device. (2) I am not Indian, but from what I've gathered (through coworkers and media) is that it's not unreasonable that women should avoid being out alone late at night. [..]

[..] Whether that's an exaggeration or not, it gives credibility to your company's decision as it suggests they are enhancing the security of a group of employees who would otherwise be disproportionately at risk; not just being sexist. (3) As to the unpaid overtime, if it is culturally/contractually inappropriate, you should address that. My understanding of Indian work culture isn't fantastic so I can't judge what avenue you should explore here. On your mention of overtime pay being expected, I would address this with the company, formally via HR if your manager doesn't want to hear it.

@ZaphodBeeblebrox so you're again and again making appeals to authority. "because I have a higher degree than those louts doing the work I'm better than them and can do their job without training". It's simply not so. I've a bachelor's in engineering physics, that doesn't make me automatically better at using a CNC machine than someone with a vocational degree in mechanical engineering. Heck, I'd be utterly lost with a CNC machine, despite having learned how to use its old fashioned manual predecessor, I'd need extensive training.

How I would handle this situation:
Firstly, Stop having 'conversations' with your Boss, Start putting things in an Email and writing (this is a really good habit to get into when working in the corporate world - always CYA).
The next steps is what to put into said email:

What your desired outcome is: "I want to be certified to do XYZ", "I want to handle ABC responsibilities"
Why you think you are ready to do the above
What you have done to demonstrate said readiness or prepate to undertake those responsibilities.
A Timeline as to when you want this to happen
Agreed Metrics on what constitutes success
What you need from your Boss.

That sounds like a lot - but as a hypothetical email:
Hi Boss,
I want to take the next step in my career and move to a role of Analyst. In the last 3 months I have demonstrated the skills necessary - for example insert anecdote about where you handled additional responsibility. I have been upskilling in my own time familiarizing myself with our procedures manual.
Ideally I would like this to happen in the next 3-6 months. I would like you to outline some goals that I can aim towards and what the criteria of achieving those goals are so that when I achieve them, we can revisit this and talk about my promition into the analysis team.
Thanks.

An email is not an option.. The company doesn't issue emails to employees lower than managerial level.  The rest of whatever you pointed out here, I have already tried, to no avail..

@ZaphodBeeblebrox - Use a professional, but personal email account. firstname.lastname@gmail.com or something similar. If it is not done in writing, it didnt happen. You can also CC in your Bosses Boss too.

@ZaphodBeeblebrox if not an email, there will be an internal mail system. Get out that typewriter and write your diatribe to the board of directors as to why your manager and all your colleagues suck.
